How do I hang some prints on a rough finish wall?
I'm currently in the process of moving into my moved out siblings room and want to redecorate, and also, I am a total DIY/home improvement noob. I am planning on hanging 21 (3 rows, 7 columns) small square artworks and album covers on a wall. The wall (solid brick wall) is a rough finish (see attached picture) so just sticking them on with 3M tape or other adhesives would probably not be the ideal solution, as they might not grip to the rough finish all that well and would damage it in case I want to remove it? I also have some left over pre-drilled holes (3 sets of 2 holes, see attached image) from a cupboard he had hanging on the wall I could utilize. I am going to repaint the wall in a dark green shade, if that information helps.
Is there an optimal way I could hang them? I'm thinking individually using some sort of nail or thumbtack for every print might not look great.
Any ideas are appreciated!


It seems there's little harm in actually trying the 3M strips. They still can work atop a rough/bumpy surface - it compresses and so gains a grip over imbalanced surfaces, you can even put two atop each other. I guess it depends if the pictures and frames weigh a lot. The biggest problem with these is that people often fail to prepare the surface adequately.

The classic solution would be a picture rail. Traditionally, this was a special kind of molding around at the top of the wall, designed so fittings could be hooked over it, with wires hanging from those to support the pictures. You will see this arrangement frequently in galleries, where the arrangement of pictures may be changed on a frequent basis, since once the rail is mounted and a small investment made in hardware it allows the wires to be adjusted as needed for any layout.
There is a modern version which uses metal rails rather than wooden moldings to support the hooks from which the wires hang. The choice between that and the traditional wooden solution is very much a matter of personal taste and style.

The benefit of this kind of arrangement is not having to drill individual holes for each picture using a hammer drill in the brick wall.

You have three sets of two-hole groups where the cupboard used to be attached. If those sets of holes are widely-enough-spaced, you may be able to get a single sheet of plywood or MDF large enough to hold all your pictures (usual USA sizes are 4x8, 5x8, 4x10, all in feet, other sizes may be available), and attach the ply/MDF sheet using the existing holes and whatever screws will fit the existing inserts in the wall.
Fill or cover the sheet mounting screws in a decorative way, then paint the ply/MDF sheet as desired. Then use a normal wall mounting device to hang each picture on the ply/MDF sheet.
